# What fingering do you think is better for "bass/chord" left-hand line?

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

Here is one of million piano arrangements of Ed Sheeran's "Perfect" that I've chosen for learning. And now I'm stuck trying to choose between two fingerings for left-hand line in this part (marked with red on the picture).

1. 5 for bass note and 531 for chord
2. or 5 for bass note and 421 for chord

Both of them comfortable and easy enought for me, but I consider this piece not just as piece, but also as exercise to master different left-hand lines (chords, arpeggio, bass/chord, and so on), so I'm trying to choose the fingering that is more common for such lines to master them for better skills development.

Seems like 5-421 is better for fast passages (because hand jump between bass and chord is shorter), but 5-531 seems a bit more comfortable for part marked with green on pictire (like 5-531-5**2**1-531), and I'm not sure that mixing theese fingering schemes is a good idea in learning-purposes terms.

So, what do you think will be better, looking from this prospective?

Context: I'm a 3-month-practice piano beginner, but with well-developeg fingers coordination (20 years of 10-fingers blind typing on computer keyboard, advanced-amateur guitar 15 years experience and so on). For now I've learned 6 piano pieces with about the same level of difficulty that this one is.

[image: Ed Sheeran "Perfect" mm. 1–30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 531.

As you've observed, both 531 and 421 are fine, and pianists use both. However, since your purpose is to exercise standard hand positions, 531 is the canonical position for root position triads, which all of these chords are (except the one identified to be played 521).

You'll encounter plenty of opportunities to exercise the 421 version as you continue to play, but master 531 first.